# Changing font color in cell on double-click

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel (using VBA) I want to change the color of the check marks from gray to green on double-click, then back to gray again on double-click (basically a toggle). Current code is below - NOTHING I have tried has worked. Please help.

Here is the image. The font is Wingdings, character code is 252, font colors are #BEBEBE and #008000. I want those gray check marks to change to green on double click and if double clicked again, back to gray. This is in a range of cells (B7 to C150).

[image: screenshot]

CODE:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 2 Then
Cancel = True
End If

If Target.Column = 3 Then
Cancel = True
End If

With Target.Font.Color
    If Not .Font.Color = vb15 Then
        .ColorIndex = vb10
    ElseIf Not .Font.Color = vb10 Then
        .ColorIndex = vb15
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

This will work, if the color is red or blue initially:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Target
        If .Column <> 2 And .Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
        Cancel = True

        If .Font.Color = vbBlue Then
            .Font.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf .Font.Color = vbRed Then
            .Font.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    End With    
End Sub
```

I could not find `vb10` or `vb15`, I guess these are some font colors generated by you. The idea in the event is to `Exit Sub`, if you are not happy with the condition.

---

Even better, if you decided to use Select Case with default option:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Target
        If .Column <> 2 And .Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
        Cancel = True

        Select Case .Font.Color
            Case vbBlue
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            Case vbRed
                .Font.Color = vbBlue
            Case Else
                .Font.Color = vbBlue
        End Select
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a Cancel = True or the double-click could initiate an in-cell edit.

Comment: My bad; I thought it was the same as the OP's. Shouldn't you still have one to dismiss the right-click menu?

Comment: @Jeeped - that is strange, and I thought that the OP's was with right click... Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: It did! Thank you!  I had to add Cancel = True because other cells need different actions, and added the RGB(X,Y,Z) for the color codes, but the rest was perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: I added the following code. I know I could have tightened this up but I'm a newbie at it so I separate things to make it easier for now:
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Cancel = True
End If

If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Cancel = True
End If

Comment: @twoawesomedogs - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem here is the colors. Use one of the following ways to define and verify the color.

```
Target.Font.Color = -16776961

Target.Font.Color = vbRed

Target.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Additionally you should only have target in your with command.

```
With Target
    If Not .Font.Color = vb15 Then
        .ColorIndex = vb10
```